# shiny app running no problem locally but gets disconnected by server

Tags: r, shiny

I have tested extensively of my shiny app locally and it's running smoothly without any problem but after I deployed on shiny.io (I tried aws-ec2 server with high memory as well) it shows below problem after initiate running an analysis about 10 seconds.

[image]

Due the apps' complexity, I am unable to paste all scrip here but here is some key information. Some suggestions how to debug it?

I deployed by using `rsconnect`

```
...
shinyApp(ui, server, options = list(height = 1100))
options(repos=BiocManager::repositories())
getOption("repos")
library(rsconnect)
rsconnect::deployApp("Finishline.Rmd")
```

The end of the log file:

```
2020-02-08T14:58:29.968642+00:00 shinyapps[1746000]: label: runapp (with options) 
2020-02-08T14:58:29.968122+00:00 shinyapps[1746000]:   ordinary text without R code
2020-02-08T14:58:29.968123+00:00 shinyapps[1746000]: 
2020-02-08T14:58:29.968230+00:00 shinyapps[1746000]: 
  |                                                                            
  |......................................................................| 100%
2020-02-08T14:58:29.969255+00:00 shinyapps[1746000]:  $ echo    : logi FALSE
2020-02-08T14:58:29.969620+00:00 shinyapps[1746000]:  $ comments: chr ""
2020-02-08T14:58:29.968778+00:00 shinyapps[1746000]: List of 4
2020-02-08T14:58:29.970454+00:00 shinyapps[1746000]: 
2020-02-08T14:58:29.976354+00:00 shinyapps[1746000]: 
2020-02-08T14:58:29.977352+00:00 shinyapps[1746000]: output file: /tmp/Rtmprhbx2g/RNASeq-Finishline.knit.md
2020-02-08T14:58:29.970034+00:00 shinyapps[1746000]:  $ warning : logi FALSE
2020-02-08T14:58:29.970434+00:00 shinyapps[1746000]:  $ message : logi FALSE
2020-02-08T14:58:29.977354+00:00 shinyapps[1746000]: 
2020-02-08T14:58:29.981749+00:00 shinyapps[1746000]: /opt/connect/ext/pandoc2/pandoc +RTS -K512m -RTS /tmp/Rtmprhbx2g/RNASeq-Finishline.utf8.md --to html4 --from markdown+autolink_bare_uris+tex_math_single_backslash+smart --output /tmp/Rtmprhbx2g/file7542ce72bc.html --email-obfuscation none --standalone --section-divs --template /opt/R/3.6.2/lib/R/library/rmarkdown/rmd/h/default.html --no-highlight --variable highlightjs=1 --css my.css --id-prefix section- --variable 'theme:bootstrap' --mathjax --variable 'mathjax-url:https://mathjax.rstudio.com/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML' --lua-filter /opt/R/3.6.2/lib/R/library/rmarkdown/rmd/lua/pagebreak.lua --lua-filter /opt/R/3.6.2/lib/R/library/rmarkdown/rmd/lua/latex-div.lua 
2020-02-08T14:58:30.049414+00:00 shinyapps[1746000]: 
2020-02-08T14:58:30.049416+00:00 shinyapps[1746000]: Output created: /tmp/Rtmprhbx2g/file7542ce72bc.html
```

Comment: Hard to say without more information. Maybe some hardcoded path or missing components could make it fail on the server.

Comment: Have spent a few days and still can't spot the bug

Comment: Without additional info it could be just about anything. Does this happen when the app is in the midst of heavy computations (data aggregation, predictions, etc.) or when it is idle as well? Asking because I had problems with websocket timing out on a Shiny app some time ago.